# How to get request uri from location.href in javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom

What I get from `location.href` is like this:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
```

But I only want to get `questions/ask` (no `/` at the first character)

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 36):

`location.pathname.substr(1)` would that be.

Comment: @wamp `substr` has an optional length and `substring` has an optional end index. In this case of having the start position and just wanting everything after, they would do the same thing.

Comment: How can I do using an `href` string variable instead of location.pathname ?

Answer (score 16):

The `location` object has a [`pathname`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_pathname.asp) property.

This will give you `/questions/ask` and to remove the first character, use `substring(1)`:

```
var path = location.pathname.substring(1);
```

Comment: Which is better ,`substr` or `substring`?

Comment: @wamp: There is no *better* (what do you mean with that anyway?). They work differently. `substr` takes a length as second parameter, and `substring` another index (up to which the string should be extracted). In this case it does not matter which one you use (and I *assume* that internally it is the same function anyway).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `location.pathname.substring(1)`

Answer (score 1):

```js
var uri = window.location.href.substr(window.location.protocol.length + window.location.hostname.length + 2);
```

This code also includes GET and HASHTAGS (basically everything after hostname)

Answer (score 1):

If you need the query params you can use:

```
var path = (window.location.pathname+window.location.search).substr(1);
```

If you need access to the `hash` as well you can use:

```
var path = (window.location.href.replace(window.location.origin, '')).substr(1);
```